# quarkus aws lambda function - cdi doesn't work in handler-class

Tags: jakarta-ee, aws-lambda, quarkus

currently, I try to implement a **AWS Lambda function** with **quarkus**.
 The problem is that I can not use cdi within my handler class.
For example, if I would like to inject the Greeter class (sample above), it is always null (**dependency injection doesn't work here with quarkus**).
Therefore, I get a NullPointer Exception on AWS.

NullPointerExceptionon AWS-Lambda-Console:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.aws.vehicles.constructibility.boundary.ConstructibilityLambdaHandler.handleRequest(ConstructibilityLambdaHandler.java:24)",
    "sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)",
    "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
  ]
}
```

I use the following quarkus-version:   `<quarkus.version>0.16.1</quarkus.version>`
(but I have also tried it with previous versions)

The code of the lambda-handler:

```
public class MyLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<SimpleRequest, String> {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyLambdaHandler.class.getName());

  @Inject
  Greeter greeter;

  @Override
  public String handleRequest(SimpleRequest simpleRequest, Context context) {
    return greeter.sayGoodMorning();
  }
}
```

The greeter-class is a very simple class that is annotated with @ApplicationScoped:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Greeter {

  public String sayGoodMorning(){
    return "good morning, hackers :)";
  }
}
```

It would be very nice if someone can me?

Comment: I think you must annotation the MyLambdaHandler with `@ApplicationScoped`

Comment: hi alexandre, no, that did not help :(

Comment: Dou have a beans.xml file? What is in it?

Comment: hi, it is clarified for me. I got support from quarkus. the reason is: CDI within a aws lambda handler in quarkus only works if you use the native-image.
The native image needs the GraalVM that is currently only supported for  Linux and Mac.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are also struggling with such an issue:
Make sure to set the Handler (template.yml under Resource -> Project -> Properties)to the io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest. Don't forget that you are using Quarkus so quarkus's handler have to be used.